# How to use Highcharts Export Server with ECMA 6 features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, highcharts

I am using Highcharts Stock and Export Server. It works fine, but there are 3 JS syntaxes that cause errors. Export Server fails to generate image.

1. Arrow Functions
2. Backticks string interpolation
3. CSS.Escape

I tried updating Node and NPM but that did not help. These issues only occur with Export Server; Chrome works fine.

Highcharts Export Server  v2.1.0
Node 18.7.0
NPM 8.15.0

I tried using Babel to transpile to an older version of JS, but that caused other errors:

1. Unexpected token 'const'
2. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
3. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

So,

1. Is this issue coming from Node, NPM or Highcharts? Why doesn't it support modern JS?
2. How can I update to work with modern JS?
3. Why does the transpiled code raise errors?

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

chart.json

```
{
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2],
      "type": "line"
    }
  ]
}
```

annotate.js

```
function annotate(chart){
    chart.renderer.text('Annotate', 20, 20)
        .add();

    // const foo = CSS.escape('foo');
}
```

command line

```
highcharts-export-server -infile chart.json -type png -outfile chart.png -logLevel 4 --allowCodeExecution 1  --callback annotate.js
```

If it succeeds, it will generate a chart.png:
[image: Success]

If the `CSS.escape` line is not commented out, then it fails and generates this image:
[image: Failure]

Comment: Hi, could you explain a way how you exporting a chart and give sample of your code to check? Perfect will be working example code and not working with ES6.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus - Please see update.

Comment: I confirm that when using callback they do not support es6 standards, but the node export server is written with this standard, I will report this and investigate.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus - I found a solution. I used Babel plugins to transpile the String Interpolation and Arrow Functions. A Polyfill works for `CSS.escape()`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this was my second suggestion for you. In the meantime, we checking why it is not compatible with ES6.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus - Thank you. I looked into it and it seems that the limitation comes from PhantomJS. PhantomJS has not been updated in several years, and it looks like it may not be updated in the future.

Comment: We have created a new version of the export server which doesn't have such problems, because it will require a minimum of node 16 to work and Puppetter runs on headless chrome and is constantly being updated.
We will be releasing it soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this issue coming from Node, NPM or Highcharts? Why doesn't it support modern JS?
   It is coming from PhantomJS, which the Export Server uses to render the charts.
2. How can I update to work with modern JS?
   Not really possible, because PhantomJS has not been updated for several years.
3. Why does the transpiled code raise errors?
   Phantom JS does not support the `require` function, among other code constructs that Babel will create.

The solution I found was to use Babel and a Polyfill (for `CSS.escape()`).

Babel provides "plugins" to convert the offending JS. The normal Babel Browser targets generated code that had constructs that could not be used, such as `require`.

Babel config (in its entirety). Not targets are specified.:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```